# Is MemcacheService fundamentally a singleton

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-endpoints

The answer to this question seems obvious, but I need to be completely sure. So if answer can provide authoritative reference with clear non-ambiguous statements, that would be great.

Say I have the following two methods

```
public CollectionResponse<Dog> getDogs(Identification request){
  MemcacheService syncCacheDog = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
  syncCacheDog.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));
  // ........
  value = (byte[]) syncCacheDog.get(key); // read from cache
    if (value == null) {
      // get value from other source
      // ........

      syncCacheDog.put(key, value); // populate cache
    }
  // ........
}

public CollectionResponse<Cat> getCats(Identification request){
  MemcacheService syncCacheCat = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
  syncCacheCat.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));
  // ........
  value = (byte[]) syncCacheCat.get(key); // read from cache
    if (value == null) {
      // get value from other source
      // ........

      syncCacheCat.put(key, value); // populate cache
    }
  // ........
}
```

Are syncCacheDog and syncCacheCat pointing to the same map? Or if I want them to be pointing to the same map, do I have to create

```
static MemcacheService syncCache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
```

and then use `syncCache` inside both methods?

On the other hand, if it is a singleton, how do I maintain two different caches? I.e. can someone please copy and paste one of my methods and show it written with a namespace and instead of dealing with generic byte to deal with a specific object such as Dog?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from my experience with GAE and its documentation, Memcache service is a singleton. Even more, different versions of the application all see the same cache.

In order to maintain different caches do the usual: use a prefix. Maintaining a unique set of prefixes for different classes should be relatively easy - have an enum somewhere, keeping track of the maximum prefix. And never reuse the old prefix numbers.

```
public enum MemcachePrefix {
  DOGS(1),
  CATS(2);
  // Max: 2.
  public final int value;
  private MemcachePrefix (int value) {this.value = value;}
};

public class Dog {
  static final MemcachePrefix MEMCACHE_PREFIX = MemcachePrefix.DOGS;
};

class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    System.out.println (dog.MEMCACHE_PREFIX);
  }
}
```

There is also [Namespaces](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Using_namespaces_with_the_Memcache). Instead of manually adding the prefix to the cache key you can use it as a namespace, letting GAE do the key manipulations for you.